# How to print/convert an object/nested hash to a string/json?

Tags: ruby, json, object, hash, type-conversion

The FlickRaw lib returning an **"#< FlickRaw::ResponseList:0x007fbe843a9ea0 >"** object (if I print it), which after applying .to_hash method is converted to a hash, which I can print using puts:

```
 {"id":"9490885638","secret":"4c05132e6a","server":"7293","farm":8,"dateuploaded":"1376261143",
"isfavorite":0,"license":"0","safety_level":"0","rotation":0,
"owner":"#<FlickRaw::Response:0x007fbe843a9ea0>",
"title":"stolen memories.","description":"Dresden, 2013.\nPlatz vor der Semperoper.",
"visibility":"#<FlickRaw::Response:0x007fbe843b1790>",
"dates":"#<FlickRaw::Response:0x007fbe843bb3a8>", ... }
```

So how can I deeply convert the return value to see all nested values/structures if I print it (not seeing some "#< FlickRaw::Response:0x007fbe843a9ea0 >" hashes)?

P.S. these doesn't work for me [ [Ruby Hash converted to JSON only shows object names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728054/ruby-hash-converted-to-json-only-shows-object-names?rq=1) ]

Comment: Did you try to convert it to Yaml ?

Comment: similar behaviour: `- !ruby/object:FlickRaw::Response` instead of `#< FlickRaw::Response >`